# Where is save data stored for Superhot?

Tags: superhot

I want to transfer my save files for Superhot to my new Windows desktop.

Where does Superhot store save data? Can progress be transferred between computers?

Comment: [PC Gaming Wiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Superhot#Save_game_data_location) generally has save and configuration file paths for any game with a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\LocalLow\SUPERHOT_Team\SUPERHOT\super.hot

When no file is present there, the game starts from scratch. Re-copying in my save successfully restored my progress.